# What does a leaf size of 1 in K-neighbors regression mean?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperparameter-tuning, k-nn

I am doing hyperparameter tuning + cross validation and I'm constantly getting that the optimal size of the leaf should be 1. Should I worry? Is this a sign of overfitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leaf_size` should have zero effect on the performance of the model. Its effect is on construction of the lookup object, which affects training and prediction *time*, but not the results.

The best parameters are probably just breaking ties by value of this parameter, so the smallest is chosen. You can inspect the `GridSearchCV` attribute `cv_results_` to be sure. It should also contain training and prediction times, which might inform what value you ultimately want to select.